# Kivy: Permission Denied when subprocess run executable file on android

Tags: kivy

I have built c code as android executable file and tried to run it with kivy app using subprocess.run("main").
But it says PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'main'.
I tried to push and run it with adb on android emulator, it failed, Permission denied: 'main'.
So, adb shell > chmod +x main, then it works.
How to run an executable file with kivy python on android?
Thanks.